# Python regex multi line matching

Tags: python, regex

**I have to match multiple lines in python.**

```
group one start
line 1 data
group end
group two start
group two data
group end
```

**on the above string how to get below output**

```
[group one start \n line 1 data \n group end, group two start \n group two data \n group end]
```

**I have tried below code but not working**

```
import re 

re.findall(r'group.*start.*group end',re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

for info in data:
   print info
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, the expected output you have provided is not valid python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, an expression somewhat similar to:

```
\bgroup [\s\S]*? start\b[\s\S]*?\bgroup end\b
```

[DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/jZ6G15/1/)

or:

```
\bgroup .*? start\b.*?\bgroup end\b
```

[DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/BgEiBg/1/)

with a `DOTALL` flag might be working here.

#### Test with `DOTALL`:

```
import re

regex = r"\bgroup .*? start\b.*?\bgroup end\b"

test_str = """
group one start
line 1 data
group end
group two start
group two data
group end
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Test without `DOTALL`:

```
import re

regex = r"(\bgroup [\s\S]*? start\b[\s\S]*?\bgroup end\b)"

test_str = """
group one start
line 1 data
group end
group two start
group two data
group end

"""


print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['group one start\nline 1 data\ngroup end', 'group two start\ngroup two data\ngroup end']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jZ6G15/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jZ6G15/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: but how to get array of output

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the text based on the pattern `group end`, but without capturing it using a look-behind

```
>>> import re
>>> text_data = """group one start
... line 1 data
... group end
... group two start
... group two data
... group end"""
>>> 
>>> re.split(r'(?<=group end)\n', text_data)
['group one start\nline 1 data\ngroup end', 'group two start\ngroup two data\ngroup end']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code working for me**

```
a = """group one start
line 1 data
group end
group two start
group two data
group end
"""
all_m = re.findall(r'group.*?start.*?group end',a,re.DOTALL)
for m in all_m:
    print(m)
    print("**********")
```

**Output**

```
group one start
line 1 data
group end
*************
group two start
group two data
group end
*************
```